# Mirror modifier not showing other half of mesh

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I always have the same problem when I try to use my mirror modifier: nothing happens. It's very frustrating, and simply can't find how to fix this. Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is because you set the wrong mirror axis.

On your screenshot, we see that it's the Y axis you want to mirror (as the center point is on the edge which is on the side of the green arrow: Y axis)

So, try to set mirror axis to **"Y"** instead of "X".